# Algorithms crash when processing large amounts of data in array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, overflow

The code:

```
int* NewArr = CreateArray(size);
FillRandom(NewArr,size);
Quicksort(NewArr,0,size-1);
```

Functions:

```
int* CreateArray(int length){
    int* arr= new int[length];
    return arr;
}

void FillRandom(int *array, int size){
   for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
      array[i]=rand()%20;
   }

}

void Quicksort (int* array, int left, int right){
   if(left<right)
   {
      int m=left;
      for(int i=left+1;i<=right;i++)
         if(array[i]<array[left])
            swap(array[++m],array[i]);
      swap(array[left],array[m]);
      Quicksort(array,left,m-1);
      Quicksort(array,m+1,right);
   }
}
```

The algorithm works fine for 30-50k of elements. Then it won't work on 100k, crashes with stack overflow exception. Can anyone give me a hint of why is that? I thought it's because of int limit, but it's 32768 yet this code works for 50k elements.

Comment: You should be using `i` in your recursive calls to `Quicksort`, not `m`.  You are basically reducing the right partition by one unit with every call, causing a recursive depth of 100,000.  No wonder you are getting stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You may be reaching the maximum stack size on your computer, further an "int" type can be different depending on your operating system. I would recommend just using "long long" or better yet "size_t" if you believe the int to be a problem.

However, based on the information at hand you may have reached the max stack size.This could be because of the recursion (each time you save a new left and right variable), each level all the way down generates a large number of stack variables. As mellamokb already mentioned, you are not iterating properly for quicksort, essentially you are creating 100k recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only using numbers in the range [0,20) you will encounter subarrays with all identical numbers. If you have such a subarray of length K, the recursive depth when doing this subarray will be K as you do subarrays of length K-1, K-2, K-3, ... If you start out with 100,000 elements, then you should expect values of K in the range of 5,000. That may very well cause a stack overflow. Try temporary to remove the % 20 in FillRandom.

Even if you don't get a stack overflow, you will get O(n^2) runtime. That is bad.